# Why does Kerberos 5 use initial vector of 0?

Tags: security, encryption, kerberos, cbc-mode

According to my understanding on initial vectors in CBC encryption, initial vectors should be random, changed by messages, and protected from predictable modification. However, Kerberos 5 seems to be using CBC but with initial vector of 0. 0 is not random and does not seem to be changed by messages. Why does Kerberos 5 uses such initial vector and how is 0 secure while it is not random?

Comment: Kerberos is a large spec, could you show where the initial vector of zeros is specified?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Since I have just started studying Kerberos, I am not sure how I can specify exact part within Kerberos.. I am studying the part on how Kerberos uses Cipher-Block Chaining to encrypt `krb_priv` messages with initialization vector of 0.

Comment: The spec is defined in RFC 3962 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3962). It's not explicitly called out in the spec why, but for historical and protocol-specific reasons. There's no good way to send an IV without increasing the message size (dumb reason, but compatibility was paramount).